# How to fix the " 'd3' was used before it was defined" error

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, adobe-brackets

I've been watching tutorials for building charts in `d3.js` but I'm stuck on this piece of code. In the video, the name "Jennifer Jerome" is highlighted and increased in font size. I literally have the same code but nothing is happening.

I keep getting the error:

> d3 was used before it was defined. 
>    `d3.selectAll('.item:nth-child(3)')`

...but not sure what it means. I feel like its something simple and obvious. Do you guys have any suggestions? Thank you! (I'm using Brackets by the way)

This is a screencap of the tutorial example:
[image: This is a screencap of the tutorial example]

This is a screencap of my code with the error (Disregard the `index.html` being in the `_` folder. It's currently back in the root directory but it still does not work):
[image: this is a screencap of my code with the error.]

And this is a screencap of my index:
[image: And this is a screencap of my index]

Comment: Provide your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `d3.js` is referenced before `script.js` in `index.html` file

Comment: It was referenced before  `script.js` . I switched it around so that now 

`<script src="../D3/script.js"></script>` is first and 
`<script src="../D3/_/d3.min.js"></script>` is second.

But still, nothing happens.

Comment: I just uploaded a screencap of my `index.html` so you can view the code.

Answer (score 0):

I expect the problem is that you are not including the d3 library in your HTML file.

Do you have something like this in your HTML file? If not, you should.

`<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I have d3 in my HTML but as the d3..min.js file. It reads as:

`<script src="../D3/_/d3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: If you go into the developer console and type `d3` and press enter, do you get a `d3 is not defined` or similar error? As @bumbeishvili points out, it could also be that your `d3.js` is referenced above `script.js`.

Comment: No, the message that appears is

`Object {event: null, format: function, formatPrefix: function, timeFormat: function, timeParse: function…}`

Comment: I just uploaded a screencap of my `index.html`  so you can see the code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your structure differs from the example is that your `index.html` is inside the `_` directory, and the example `index.html` is outside the `_` directory (in the root directory).

**Try moving `index.html` outside of `_`.**

Then, these paths should work.

```
<script src="_/d3.min.js">
<script src="script.js">
```

Comment: This is how it is currently formatted:

    `<script src="../D3/_/d3.min.js"></script>`
    `<script src="../D3/script.js"></script>`

The `d3` file was referenced before `script.js`

Comment: Hey, sorry I changed my answer so dramatically. It looks like I had the paths wrong again, but now I think they should work. The `../D3` is redundant, since `D3` is the directory you just `..`ed out of.

Comment: Oh, crap, I read it wrong again. The reason your structure differs from the example is that your `index.html` is inside the `_` directory, and the example `index.html` is outside the `_` directory (in the root directory). **Try moving `index.html` outside of `_`.**

Comment: I just uploaded a screencap of my `index.html` so you can get a better look at the code. But my index is in my root directory `D3` , not in `_`

Comment: Ahh, I see in the second screencap what you were talking about. I apologize, that was from when I was moving the `index.html` file around to see if it would work. Its still currently in the root directory as shown in the **third screencap**. But it is still not working.

Comment: Can you get to the `d3.min.js` script in your browser, if you access it directly? (Go to http://127.0.0.1:50665/_/d3.min.js in the browser.)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by getting the `d3.min.js` in the browser.